# сохранение jpg в наилучшем качестве C#

Tags: c#, изображения

Добрый день. Имеется код, объединяющий два изображения в одно:

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap("iphone.jpg");
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {


            int bmp1_width = bmp1.Width;
            int bmp1_height = bmp1.Height;
            Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(dialog.FileName);

            Bitmap final_bmp = new Bitmap(bmp1_width, bmp1_height);
            pictureBox1.Image = final_bmp;

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(final_bmp);

            g.DrawImage(bmp1, 0, 0, bmp1_width, bmp1_height);
            g.DrawImage(bmp2, 24, 103, 242, 342);
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.Dispose();

            pictureBox1.Invalidate();

            final_bmp.Save("D:\\output1.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Можно ли как-то гарантировано сохранить это обобщенное изображение, чтобы в итоге оно имело максимально возможное качество?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если присмотреться, то вы сами можете увидеть, что отображаются всякие квадратики и тому подобное. В оригинальном изображении такого нет.

Comment: Если вы спрашиваете как задать качество сжатия - вам сюда https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
using (Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\TestPhoto.jpg"))  
{  
    ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);  

    myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 0L);//вот этот 0L можешь заменить на 100L - это измениние уровня компрессии
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter; 

    bmp1.Save(@"C:\TestPhotoQualityZero.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);  
}
```

А лучше сохраняй в .png